# Showing json field in Django admin

Tags: python, json, django

I have an Django model as follows:

```
class BodyHeight(models.Model):
    seats = models.ForeignKey(to=Seats)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127, null=True, blank=True)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    data = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Body heights"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

And in the data field I store the json data, as follows:

```
{"url": "https://some_url=/BE?category=COMMERCIAL, "images": ["url_to_some_image"]}
```

And I want to show in the Django admin panel only the url from that field.

Now I have:

```
class BodyHeightAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name', )
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'key', )
    list_display_links = ('id', 'name', 'key', )

admin.site.register(BodyHeight, BodyHeightAdmin)
```

That is without the data field. If I add the `data` field in `list_display` it shows than whole json (ugly format), but I want only the `url`.

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I changed the `bodyHeightAdmin` class as follows:

```
class BodyHeightAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name', )
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'key', 'url', )
    list_display_links = ('id', 'name', 'key', )

    def url(self, instance):
        data = json.loads(instance.data)
        return data["url"]
```

And it worked.

Comment: For my case it works without json.loads:



`data = instance.data`

Comment: works for me `def my_field_name(self, instance) return instance.my_json_field["my_field_name"]`

Answer (score 60):

My solution for adding basic formatting for JSONField in Django Admin (Django>=3.1):

```
import json
import logging

from django.db.models import JSONField 
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import widgets


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class PrettyJSONWidget(widgets.Textarea):

    def format_value(self, value):
        try:
            value = json.dumps(json.loads(value), indent=2, sort_keys=True)
            # these lines will try to adjust size of TextArea to fit to content
            row_lengths = [len(r) for r in value.split('\n')]
            self.attrs['rows'] = min(max(len(row_lengths) + 2, 10), 30)
            self.attrs['cols'] = min(max(max(row_lengths) + 2, 40), 120)
            return value
        except Exception as e:
            logger.warning("Error while formatting JSON: {}".format(e))
            return super(PrettyJSONWidget, self).format_value(value)


class JsonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        JSONField: {'widget': PrettyJSONWidget}
    }
```

Usage:

```
admin.site.register(models.MyModel, JsonAdmin)
```

For Django < 3.1 you have to import JSONField in this way:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
```

Hope it will help you!

Comment: Thank you. Really clean solution.

Comment: Works when the field is _not_ readonly, but isn't applied to a JSONField that was defined in _readonly_fields_.

Comment: for anybody trying this with django 3.X and a JSONField (the default one from django) in your models.py  you would have to `from django.db.models import JSONField` instead of `django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField`

Comment: Any solutions for readonly fields?

Answer (score 3):

To show formatted JSON in admin page I recommend you python library `django-json-widget`. It is easy to use and has great features (you can edit formatted JSON).

1) install library `pip install django-json-widget`

2) add django-json-widget to installed_apps in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_json_widget',
    ...
)
```

3) add following code to admin.py (do not forget to change YourModel with your real model name)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.postgres import fields
from django_json_widget.widgets import JSONEditorWidget
from .models import YourModel


@admin.register(YourModel)
class YourModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    formfield_overrides = {
        fields.JSONField: {'widget': JSONEditorWidget},
    }
```

Comment: Do you use postgres? This solution only works if you are using postgres. @Florent

Comment: There must be something wrong in my code and/or I don't understand how to configure the admin.py

Comment: Share some code with me and I will try to help you. @Florent

Comment: This package was updated last time in 2021 and supports Django <=2.2

Comment: This package breaks when upgrading to the latest Django 4.2 LTS version

Answer (score 3):

Here's a case valid for when the JSONField is set for readonly

```py
# set 'url' editable=False in model defintion

class BodyHeightAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('name', )
    list_display = ('id', 'name', 'key', 'get_pprint_url', )
    list_display_links = ('id', 'name', 'key', )
    readonly_fields = ('get_pprint_url', )

    def url(self, instance):
        data = json.loads(instance.data)
        return data["url"]

    actions = [
        'process_webhook_events',
        'reset_webhook_events'
    ]

    def get_pprint_url(self, obj=None):
        result = ''
        if obj and obj.url:
            result = json.dumps(obj.url, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
            # keep spaces
            result_str = f'<pre>{result}</pre>'
            result = mark_safe(result_str)
        return result
    get_pprint_url.short_description = 'url'
```